# How to wake up Android from sleep by c2dm notification and start activity?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

How to wake up Android from sleep by c2dm notification and start activity?

I want to create something like incoming call.

Comment: you can use Alarm Manager for it.

Comment: why should I use AlarmManager? I don't need to schedule anything. I want to start activity when c2dm push notification received.

Comment: did you find an answer - I have a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897387/how-to-wake-up-an-android-on-incoming-data

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a BroadcastReceiver.  See [Android C2DM documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#writing_apps).

Comment: Sorry. The question in not about that. I've already implemented c2dm receiver. Currently I need to make a full wake up of device and start specific activity when notification is received. Something like skyp incoming call that wake up the device.