# How to wake up an Android on incoming data

Tags: android, networking, service, wakelock

I want an Android service, which is listening for data (I have tried TCP and UDP) to wake up the service/phone when data arrives.

Currently the phone stays asleep when IP data arrives *and* that data is lost.  Is this normal for Android?  I see sleeps of 2+ hours several times a day, and 7+ hour sleeps when I am asleep.

Does GCM provided a solution which wakes up a service/phone when a message arrives.

I need messages to be displayed within a few seconds of them being sent from the server.

Can this only be achieved by keeping the CPU running all day long?  Is there no interrupt from the GSM modem on the arrival of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, *if* you have an outstanding socket connection over mobile data to a server, that socket connection is maintained while in sleep mode, and incoming packets will wake up the phone out of sleep mode (briefly) to deliver the data.

The same is *not* true of WiFi (and presumably not for hardwired Ethernet, either). You would need to hold a `WakeLock` and a `WifiLock`.

> Does GCM provided a solution which wakes up a service/phone when a message arrives.

Yes, but...

> I need messages to be displayed within a few seconds of them being sent from the server.

First, GCM has no service-level guarantee. I am not aware of any solution that does, including anything that you might roll yourself (e.g., MQTT).

Second, you have no idea if the device is capable of receiving any such messages (GCM or otherwise), as the device may be turned off, in airplane mode, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have a source for your first assertion about outstanding socket connections, as I'm not seeing this behaviour.

Comment: @chrisdew: "do you have a source for your first assertion about outstanding socket connections" -- Google I|O 2011 presentation on C2DM, off the top of my head. Note that you will need to wake up yourself periodically to do some sort of "heartbeat" operation to keep the socket alive, lest the mobile carrier or server drop it.

Comment: Thanks, I think that that is what I'm missing.  I'll accept the answer once I've got my code working (hopefully tomorrow).

Comment: On Orange (UK) TCP NAT timeout is > 5 mins.  UDP NAT timeout is somewhere between 30s and 2 minutes.